# How to set selected ngfor ionic2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to set selected but I tried this below it's not work
How to set selected ngfor ionic2
I tried

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Source</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="filter" >
        <ion-option value={{item.val}} *ngFor="let item of options" selected="item.val == 'pencil'">{{item.name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

it's not work ,not show selected this to default

ts

```
public options =  [
        {
            "name": "Pencils",
            "val" : "pencil"
          }
             .
             .
             .

        ];
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? What happens? Where are you setting `options`?

Comment: please update the error it's throwing in the console. !

Comment: @ExplosionPills I editted the posts

Comment: @rrmerugu it's not error but it's not show selected "pencil" to default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `ngModel`, you should set the filter to the selected item initially:

```
public filter = this.options[0].val;
```

Comment: Great!.  but, why does selected doesn't work ! https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#select shows that selected="seomthing true" should work !

Comment: @rrmerugu `[selected]="seomthing` true" use this instead because its a expression

Comment: ohh I have not tried yet >>> [selected]="seomthing true"

Comment: @ARR.s I believe this is just an issue with the Ionic documentation and that the `ngModel` binding will not work with `selected`

Answer (score 0):

`[selected]` instead of `selected` and `[value]` instead of `value` :

```
  <ion-option [value]="item.val" *ngFor="let item of options" [selected]="item.val == 'pencil'">{{item.name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

**note** :

1. use `property` when bind to static value ex: `value="someValue"`
2. use `[property]` when bind to a variable or expression ex: `[value]="getSomeValue()"`.